# 404 Error loading sp-pnp-js.js in Angular2 App

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to use sp-pnp-js in a small application I want to run on a SharePoint page.

I've imported both these ways:

```
import * as spns from "sp-pnp-js";
import { Web } from 'sp-pnp-js';
```

and I get no errors just having the imports. When it gets to this line:

```
 var web = new Web("mySharePointSite");
```

and serve the application, I get a 404 error from zone.js saying it's unable to find the sp-pnp-js.js file in my modules.

I've installed it successfully, it's in my package.json, but it will not run.

I'm doing this locally and trying to remotely access a sharepoint site, do I need to be doing this on a SharePoint site? I can't even build the project successfully in order to deploy it, so I don't know if that's right either.